# How to calculate the convolution of constant function

Tags: probability-theory

Given that $f*g(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(x-t)dt$.  Calculate $f*f$ if $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ on $[-1,1]$ and $0$ elsewhere.

So my initial thought is to calculate $\int\limits_{-1}^1 \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}dt=\frac{1}{2}$, but I know that this can not be correct because I know that $f*f*f*f\cdots$ approaches the normal distribution. So what am I doing wrong?

I know it has to do with the fact that '$g$' is shifted. So then the calculation would be $\int\limits_{-1}^x \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}dt$ or $\int\limits_{x}^1 \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}dt$, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track: 
\begin{align}
f * f(x) = &\ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{4}\chi_{[-1,1]}(t)\chi_{[-1,1]}(x - t)\,dt \\
= &\ \frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^1\chi_{[-1,1]}(x - t)\,dt.
\end{align}

Then we need to understand what happens to the integrand when $t$ ranges between $\pm1$. Notice that the integrand is different from $0$ if and only if $-1 \le x - t \le 1$, which is equivalent to $x - 1 \le t \le x+1$. Then we have the following situation: 
$$
f * f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if}\ x - 1 \ge 1\ \text{or}\ x + 1 \le -1,\\
\frac{1}{4}\int_{-1}^{x + 1}dt & \text{if}\ x \in [-2,0],\\
\frac{1}{4}\int_{x - 1}^1dt & \text{if}\ x \in [0,2].
\end{cases}
$$

This of course can be rewritten in the following nicer form:
$$
f * f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if}\ x - 1 \ge 1\ \text{or}\ x + 1 \le -1,\\
\frac{x + 2}{4} & \text{if}\ x \in [-2,0],\\
\frac{2 - x}{4} & \text{if}\ x \in [0,2].
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: The last is wrong.

Comment: I have edited, thanks for pointing that out!